# How to create 2 cell 3 row custom image listview in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

How to create 2 cell 3 row custom image listview in xamarin ?

In my Tab Page,I need to have 6 Images in the 2 Cells / 3 Rows. On Clicking the Image, will navigate to new page which has ListView Item Template.

How should i bind 6 Page Navigation - Images in my Tab Page ?

[image]

Comment: an image of what you want to have would be great so we can imagine correctly :) because maybe what you need is to use a grid or scrollview instead of a list .

Comment: @BraveHeart .. I have attached the image. ..

Comment: great and will be there any scrolling ?

Comment: There will not be any scrolling.. Image ListView will have to adapt itself for every environment - iphone 5 or 6..

Comment: Look at this link. Yours is simplified version of building calculator. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/

Comment: @yuri, any idea about image png file dimension size.  I need to have 6 images of equal size ..

Comment: you can either use highest resolution you need (you even may store images in PCL) or create different images per platform and even different images for different resolutions-for Android mdpi, xdpi, etc and for iOS x2 x3 etc. This is your call how nice you want your UI to be. The better  the more space you need. OR use vector graphics to scale your images. I haven't tried that yet but know it is possible

Comment: Thank you .., I will try it ..

Answer (score 1):

Hi what you need to use is just a grid , with three rows and two columns , they will come exactly the way you want it.

Comment: thank you .., any idea about image dimensions.. app has to work on crossplatform . Thanks